# How is request_processing_time measured?

Tags: amazon-web-services, request, amazon-elb, access-log

[Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/access-log-collection.html#access-log-entry-format)  request_processing_time is defined as "The total time elapsed, in seconds, from the time the load balancer received the request until the time it sent it to a registered instance."

But i cant figure it out 1) how is this time measured.
                    2) and what is the meaning of instance here.
 I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: I don't use AWS much, but as the docs mentions, the unit of time is seconds. By instance I imagine it means a AWS instance (a VM running and managed from your AWS account). The way is read is the amount of seconds passed since a HTTP request was made until it got routed/sent to the VM/"computer"/instance that should handle it

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza as we are using nginx, so it should denote the time taken to send request to nginx, or is there something else which is referred as instance.